# Parsing and saving the JSON values

Tags: json, rest

I have seen some examples over the internet to parse the JSON, but still I'm unable to parse and store the values into a object for the Patch operation.

```
/services/apexrest/id/00hjkl00000kl00
```

below is the sample JSON

```
{
 "Details":{
  "SSN"      : "1234",
  "FULLSSN"  : "12345678"
}
}
```

This is the Apex class that I wrote

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/id/*')
Global class Restservice{

@Httppatch
global static String doput() {

RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

 Id leadid = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.LastIndexOf('/')+1);
 Lead lead1 = [SELECT ID, isConverted FROM Lead WHERE id =: leadid];
 if(lead1.isconverted)
    {
   Blob jsonBlob = req.requestBody;
   String jsonString = jsonBlob.toString();

//I need to update the SSN and FULLSSN (From JSON) values in to this existing lead 

     return 'Success';   
    }
 else
  return 'Failure';
}


    public class Details {
        public String SSN;
        public String FULLSSN;
    }

}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all your endpoint and URL mapping for your web service don't match:

`/services/apexrest/value/00hjkl00000kl00` should be `/services/apexrest/id/00hjkl00000kl00` as per your example code.

Also your wrapper class name doesn't match the JSON example code so you can't directly serialize the JSON. Either change the JSON `Details` to `Loanoptions` or change the class name to `Details`.

Once all that is fixed you can simply take the JSON as a parameter in your method which will automatically serialize it into an object instance of your `Loanoptions` class. Let's say we've changed the JSON structure and it's now:

```
{
     "Loanoptions":{
      "SSN"      : "1234",
      "FULLSSN"  : "12345678"
    }
}
```

You can just simply do:

```
global static String doput(Loanoptions loanOptionsRecord) 
{
    // your existing code, then:

    lead1.SSN__c = loanOptionsRecord.SSN;
    lead1.Full_SSN__c = loanOptionsRecord.FULLSSN;
    update lead1;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively, if you have different input occasionally, you can use the `JSON.deserializeUntyped()`, and get only certain values from the JSON string:

```
global static String doput() 
{
    // your existing code, then:
    Map <String, Object> resultObject = (Map <String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
    Map <String, Object> detailsObject = (Map <String, Object>)resultObject.get('Details');

    lead1.SSN__c = (String)detailsObject.get('SSN');
    lead1.Full_SSN__c = (String)detailsObject.get('FULLSSN');
    update lead1;
}
```

Comment: Boris, I updated the URL sorry about that. I still don't understand how are the values being deserialized in the above code?

Comment: Salesforce performs implicit de-serialisation if you add a parameter to you input get or post method. This is helpful in case your input data is expected in a single format. If you are expecting input in different format every time, you can perform de-serialisation yourself by calling JSON.deserialize method from JSON class

Comment: @manjit_singh: I'm looking for patch operation, and I don't think the implicit de serialization would work.

Comment: I believe it will work.

Comment: I've updated my answer including an alternative way of how you can get only certain values from the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check your json for Malformed JSON

Use the following json beautifier

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Also you can use following  json2apexengine to parse your json in Apex Class

http://json2apexengine.somee.com/

use following method to deserialize your json

```
Decimal n = (Decimal)JSON.deserialize(endpoint, Decimal.class);
```

Decimal is your wrapper class